# Extending role based security to allow roles for a specific entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-security

I've used FluentSecurity in another MVC application and its great, provides a slick implementation.

I now have a requirement to offer application wide roles, plus also provide additional permission control over individiual entities.

My application manages particular locations and a user may have permissions to perform actions at one or more locations, each location has a unique id. I'll need to check a user has a particular role for the location id (effectively adding another dimension to roles). I've got my schema mapped out, along with my repo/service layers.

I was wondering if someone has tackled this type of problem before and whether its worth me trying to solve with FluentSecurity or if I should validate the user has the role required for the location on each GET/POST request (controller or service layer).

I'm getting to achieve this in FluentSecurity I'll have to roll my own policy and capture the location id from the RequestContext.RouteData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done exactly what you need to do, but creating a custom policy in FluentSecurity that handles your scenario should not be hard at all. If you feel it is, please let me know and I will have to fix that.

You can find more information on how to create custom policies here:

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Custom-policies

It sounds to me like you might want to split it into two custom policies. You then apply your custom policies like this:

```
configuration.For<SomeController>()
    .AddPolicy<CustomPolicy1>()
    .AddPolicy<CustomPolicy2>();
```